# GetElementByID at server side, asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, client-side-data, server-side-controls

I have something like that:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="lvList" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <select id="select_list">
        <option value="-1">
          select one
        </option>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
      </select>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <option value="<%# Eval("code") %>">
        <%# Eval("Name") %>
      </option>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

And I want to access `select_list` at server side, after a button get submitted..
I tried `FindControl("select_list")`, `lvList.FindControl("select_list")`, `Request.Form["select_list"]` - none of them gave my the control back..

Is there some way to get the control by its id, just like JS `getElementByID` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for academic purpose? You could write the same code with lesser markup using an `asp:DropDownList`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="select_list" runat="server"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            DataTextField="Name"
            DataValueField="code">
    <asp:ListItem Text="select one" Value="-1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you are particular about using ListView do run your HTML Control at server `runat="server"`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using a `ListView` to fill a HTML `select` rather than just using a `DropDownList`?

You can just replace the entire `ListView` with a `DropDownList` like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SampleDdl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select one" Value="-1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then, in your code behind, you can just bind the `DropDownList` like so:

```
SampleDdl.DataSource = DataSet
SampleDdl.DataValueField = "Code"
SampleDdl.DataTextField = "Name"
SampleDdl.DataBind()
```

This will automatically populate the `DropDownList` for you. Specifying the `DataValueField` will automatically populate the `Value` attributes in all the options of the `DropDownList`. Similarly, the `DataTextField` will populate the `Text` attributes.

It's also important to note that I've added `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` in my sample above - you will need to add that so that the default option of "Select one" isn't replaced by the data that is bound to the control - instead the bound data is appended after the existing option.

If you use a `DropDownList`, you can then just access the control in your code-behind by directly referring to `SampleDdl`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a control to have a server representation of itself you have to declare it with the attribute runat="server"

Try

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvList" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
  <select id="select_list" runat="server">
    <option value="-1">
      select one
    </option>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </select>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <option value="<%# Eval("code") %>">
    <%# Eval("Name") %>
  </option>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and then try accessing using 
    FindControl("select_list")

Answer (score 0):

the control you are trying to access is client side control. If you want to access it server side try adding a tag like runat="server". Something like

```
<select id="..." runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set its runat attribute to "server" and use the ListView's LayoutTemplate property to obtain it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvList" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <select id="select_list" runat="server">
        <option value="-1">
          select one
        </option>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
      </select>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <option value="<%# Eval("code") %>">
        <%# Eval("Name") %>
      </option>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```